# How to resolve between two python 3 installations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

In my terminal, when I run:

```
pip -V
```

It gives:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/abhor/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

And when I run:

```
pip3 -V
```

It gives:

```
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

I want only 1 python3.6 to be there in my system, in case there are problems in the future. How to do this?

Comment: In windows, by removing the path variable corrects this behavior. similarly from your path variable remove one which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any harm to keep it this way however you can uninstall any one of them.
and its always recommended that you use separate virtual environment for your each of your project.

to create a virtual environment

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ $ virtualenv -p your_python_version my_env_name
```

also since you are using anaconda you can use conda command like this

```
$ conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x
```